# Dilation of operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ and $K$ be two Hilbert spaces with $H\subseteq K$ and let $T\in B(H)$. An operator $A\in B(K)$ is said to be a dilation of $T$, if
$$T^n=P_HA^n|_H, \qquad n\geq 0,$$
where $P_H$ indicates the orthogonal projection on $H$.

My question: Does dilation respect the transitivity, i.e., if $A$ is a dilation of $T$ and $B$ is a dilation of $A$, can we conclude that $B$ is also a dilation of $T$?

I am not aware of any operator theoretic results from which this follows trivially. Any explanation will be of much help.

Comment: Does the equality hold for all $n$ ?

Comment: yes@Falcon. The equality holds for all n.